# How will i deploy my downloaded xap file?

Tags: apps, update, 7.x, htc

I am using HTC HD7 with wp7.8 and i want to deploy my xap file for playing game and install game in my phone. Have any way for doing this things.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Phone 7.x only allows apps to be installed via the store app itself; Whilst you can download the xap from the store, you can only use this to install on phones running Windows Phone 8.0 or later.

Answer (score 1):

This used to work on developer unlocked phones, unfortunately [it is no longer possible to unlock Windows Phone 7 devices](http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-ends-unlocking-windows-phone-7x-devices-developers-dec-31). As Rowland writes, you'll need Windows Phone 8.x to do this.